# how to use esbuild with plain javascript

Tags: javascript, bundler, esbuild

I have two files

```js
// index.js
// ... import some other modules ...
export function test() {
  alert("I'm using some modules");
}
```

and

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<div onclick="test()">test</div>
```

I can "bundle" the JS

```
esbuild index.js --outfile=www/main.js --bundle
```

But how can I use `test()` from `index.html`?

Comment: note that I'm a C-programmer with no idea about JS-tooling. I want to build a prototype. There are lots of tutorials for esbuild, all assuming that you already know 1000 other tools. Using esbuild, because all else was even more complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://esbuild.github.io/api/#global-name):

Specify a global name for the exports:

```
esbuild index.js --outfile=www/main.js --bundle --global-name=xyz
```

Then you can access it view:

```
<div onclick="xyz.test()">test</div>
```

---

However! **Don't do the above!**

Intrinsic event attributes have not been considered best practise for a couple of decades and have some areas where they give unexpected behaviour.

Use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead.

This will remove the need to include `--global-name=xyz` since you'll be using your function inside your script and not from another script elsewhere in the HTML document.

Comment: Thank you, that works. Had to move the `<div>` before the script so that its available to get by ID.

Comment: @Dill — Check out the [defer attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer) which lets you download the JS in parallel but delay executing it until the DOM is ready.

Comment: @sirion1987 — I have no idea what you did wrong. [Ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Don't forget to include a [mcve]. Follow the advice in [ask]. Include a link to this answer for context if applicable.